# Problem with Date type in mongodb use in Spring boot application

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new to the mongodb. So, I got a error when creating BasicDBObject manually for my Testcase. Error was,
`java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date`

This is how I create manually my Object.

Player.java

```
@Data
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {
  @Id private ObjectId _id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private Date dateOfBirth;
  private String jerseyNo;
  private String profileImageUrl;
}
```

Manually created Object.

```
protected static List<Player> getPlayersList() throws ParseException {

    Player player1 = new Player(ObjectId.get(), "Smith", "Andrew", new Date(), "jersey 12", "aaaaa");

    Player player2 = new Player(ObjectId.get(), "Ryan", "Cold", new Date(), "jersey 04", "bbbbbb");

    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    players.add(player1);
    players.add(player2);
    return players;
  }
```

Map Player List to Document.

```
public class Converters {
  public static List<Document> convertPojoToDocuments(List<?> dataFromDB) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Document> documentList = new ArrayList<>();
    dataFromDB.forEach(
        f -> {
          Document doc = Document.parse(gson.toJson(f));
          doc.remove("_id");
          doc.put("_id", ObjectId.get());
          documentList.add(doc);
        });
    return documentList;
  }
}
```

Add document to BasicDBObject

```
BasicDBObject rawData = new BasicDBObject();
rawData.put("data", convertPojoToDocuments(getPlayersList()));
```

Then rawData.get("data") return **dateOfBirth** Lick this
`"dateOfBirth": "Nov 20, 2020 7:05:11`.
But I need to set **dateOfBirth** Lick this `"dateOfBirth": {"$date": "2010-10-30T18:30:00Z"}`to fix my error. Can anyone give solution for that?

Comment: try using LocalDateTime instead of Date

Comment: thanks, It works for me.